# What is "??" symbol in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I found this "??" symbol in resource > ... > reset in the email input field.

is it an itinerary operator or what ?.

```
{{ $email ?? old('email') }}
```

Comment: It is the `Null Coalescing Operator`, introduced in PHP 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does double question mark (??) operator mean in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610622/what-does-double-question-mark-operator-mean-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a Laravel feature, it is PHP's. It came out in PHP 7, called the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). It basically allows you to put a "default" value if a variable is null or undefined.

### Example:

```php
$name = null;

echo $name ?? 'John'; // This will display Jhon
```