# Can I use multiple null coalescing operators || in vue just like as in php?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

When converting my code from php to js, I can't get this bit to work:

```
searchEntity.translations[0].translation ?? searchEntity.name ?? searchEntity.name_en
```

I tried using two `||`

```
searchEntity.translations[0].translation || searchEntity.name || searchEntity.name_en
```

but vue compiler only sees the first one and does't display whole component when second should be rendered, hovever if I display just second everything works:

```
searchEntity.name || searchEntity.name_en
```

however entity is polymorphic and it can be either of those 3.

I don't want to use v-if, it will need a repetitive code

(code is in the template, not computed)

**EDIT**

checking if translations exists in computed function solves issue

```
translatedName: function () {
                if(this.searchEntity.translations) {
                    return this.searchEntity.translations[0].translation
                } else {
                    return this.searchEntity.name || this.searchEntity.name_en || this.searchEntity.translation_fallback;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does PHP's `??` do?

Comment: @VLAZ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610622/what-does-double-question-mark-operator-mean-in-php

Comment: @mplungjan That would be good information to put *in this question* instead of having to look it up.

Comment: Can you explain why this code is tagged with both PHP and JS, when you only share JS code?

Comment: @NicoHaase it is converting JS from PHP - perhaps JS/PHP ppl had some shared knowledge of differences between PHP and JS that was not obvious

Comment: @Lizard we need more code. As you can see, the || operator seems to work in VUE as expected

Comment: There's ?? in JS but in cannot be used in Vue templates. The difference between || and ?? is that || is less restrictive, `searchEntity.translations[0].translation ||` will short-circuit to second part if it's falsy, i.e. empty string. Whatever your case is, it's specific to your case and values in use. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: Maybe even `if (this.searchEntity.translations && this.searchEntity.translations.length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS will not shortcut on erroneous items

An error is not falsy like it seems to be in PHP

You can use a ternary in front

```js
const searchEntity1 = {
  translations: [{
    translation: "Navn"
  }],
  name: "Nom",
  name_en: "Name"
}
const searchEntity2 = {
  translations: null,
  name: "Nom",
  name_en: "Name"
}

const searchEntity3 = {
  translations: null,
  name: null,
  name_en: "Name"
}

const getTranslation = searchEntity => {
  const translations = searchEntity.translations;
  return translations && translations.length ? 
     translations[0].translation : searchEntity.name || searchEntity.name_en;
};
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    name1: getTranslation(searchEntity1),
    name2: getTranslation(searchEntity2),
    name3: getTranslation(searchEntity3)
  }
})
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="example">
    <p>{{ name1 }}</p>
    <p>{{ name2 }}</p>
    <p>{{ name3 }}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that means, that my variables are not as expected :/

Comment: @LizardDerad re-reading and rewriting your question made me think this is a vue issue, so I changed your title and reopened

Comment: your code works for me too, it's probably because my vars are either nested objects of arrays, or final version is somewhat weird.  After debuging I'll notify what was the issue :/

Comment: @LizardDerad I made a vue version :)

Comment: @mplungjan I  tested it, work fine :D But I found issue also in my code. In some cases searchEntity object has translations, but in this case it did not, that's why it crashed. In php it handles everything, if thre's issue it moves to the next variable, in js it is not equivalent

Comment: You mean there was a console error saying length not found on searchEntity.translations  or something

Comment: almost, `Cannot read property '0' of undefined"` refering to `searchEntity.translations[0].translation`

Comment: to handle this I created whole computed function which checks if translation exists :/ was really hoping || will do the work

Comment: Yeah, I updated my code to do the same - it is easier to read