# Correct usage of the isset, recomended by IDE?

Tags: php

I am using PHPStorm and the inspection is recommending that I switch this line of code:

```
$orderings['custom'][$child->id] = isset($custom_values[$child->id]) ? $custom_values[$child->id] : $next_order++;
```

to this:

```
$orderings['custom'][$child->id] = $custom_values[$child->id] ?? $next_order++;
```

But I can't find information in the PHP documentation about this change. Are changes like this non breaking and what is the `??` doing?

Comment: It's PHP's [null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610622/what-does-double-question-mark-operator-mean-in-php)

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). Do note that `??` will produce a syntax error on any setup with `<PHP7.X`

Comment: @DarkBee that explains what this does. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement...

`$orderings['custom'][$child->id] = $custom_values[$child->id] ?? $next_order++;`

?? it work as

- if `$custom_values[$child->id]` value is not null then it use `$custom_values[$child->id]` value
- if `$custom_values[$child->id]` value is null then it use `$next_order` value