# Sum and deduct according to array list in PHP using array map

Tags: php

I have two array

```
$a = [500,0,300,0];
$b = [0, 100, 0, 100];
```

My desire output :

```
$c = [500,400,700,600];
```

I have tried by below approach, but not getting desire output.

```
<?php 

function get_c()
{
    $amount = 0;
    
    if (func_get_arg(0) > 0) {
        $amount = $amount + func_get_arg(0);
    } else {
        $amount = $amount - func_get_arg(1);
    }
    return $amount;

}
$a = [500,0,300,0];
$b = [0, 100, 0, 100];


$c = array_map(
    'get_c',
    $a,
    $b
);

print_r($c);
```

Getting output `[500,-100,300,-100]` . I understood my amount value always getting zero in if condition. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please exaplain why `$c[1]` is `400`? `0` + `100` should be `100`?

Comment: Ohhhh I think I get it now. You want to sum all previous entries in both arrays.

Comment: @David yes you are right. It's like transaction statement.

Comment: @0stone0 It's like transactions , not summation two arrays.

Comment: That's not how [map](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) functions. Read the documentation on [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) for PHP's implementation. Also check out the related operations: filter, fold/reduce and zip/convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with a simple foreach loop following your map. This loop just sums the whole result array in order.

```
foreach($c as $i => $val)
{
    if($i == 0)
        continue;
        
    $c[$i] = $c[$i-1] + $val;
}
```

Full code:

```
function get_c()
{
    $amount = 0;
    
    if (func_get_arg(0) > 0) {
        $amount = $amount + func_get_arg(0);
    } else {
        $amount = $amount - func_get_arg(1);
    }
    return $amount;

}

$a = [500,0,300,0];
$b = [0, 100, 0, 100];


$c = array_map(
    'get_c',
    $a,
    $b
);

foreach($c as $i => $val)
{
    if($i == 0)
        continue;
        
    $c[$i] = $c[$i-1] + $val;
}

print_r($c);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 500
    [1] => 400
    [2] => 700
    [3] => 600
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a simple for loop if the both array have the same indexes.

Use (after the first iteration ([`??`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610622/what-does-double-question-mark-operator-mean-in-php))) our last value in `$c` to get the new one:

```
<?php

$a = [500,0,300,0];
$b = [0, 100, 0, 100];
$c = [];

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++) {
    $c[$i] = ($c[$i - 1] ?? 0) + $a[$i] - $b[$i];
}

var_dump($c);
```

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(500)
  [1]=>
  int(400)
  [2]=>
  int(700)
  [3]=>
  int(600)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxCsMwDEV3neIPGmycgELp5AQfJJjipA3xUGJS2qGlZ3ftVIP0eP8rrSnn3qU1EXHAgPEs0khzqttb4qk6adAVgf@teq66AC3bDsVxEAuO6PGI79u2KA66CmM0PoQyPI8cfflSB6FF5@EcRMOAwxG24KmCpS/RK@yX6/OeSl/bnH8)

Comment: Both array has not same index, that's why I am using array map.

Comment: Your question shows 2 arrays with same amount of indexes

Comment: Sorry ! it was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

when you use array_map function it calls get_c for every element and initializes $amount =0 each time.
to solve this problem you can just use a simple foreach loop.

```
<?php 

function get_c($a, $b) :array
{
     $amount = 0;
     $output = array();
    
    foreach($a as $key =>$value) 
    {
        if($value >0) {
             $amount = $amount + $value;
        }
        else $amount = $amount - $b[$key];
        
        $output[] = $amount;
    }
    return $output;
}

$a = [500,0,300,0];
$b = [0, 100, 0, 100];


$c = get_c($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

I hope that answers your question